# ASP.nET Core Web Application (.NET Core RC2) - Why are items in the head tag rendered in the body tag

Tags: asp.net

If you create a new ASP.NET Core Web Application in Visual Studio 2015 and run the stock standard template app, all the tags (title, link,meta) that have been added to the head tag are rendered in the body? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue caused by having Browser link enabled.

I am not sure if this is an issue with the latest version .NET Core or if it is intentional.

Comment: Yup browserlink was doing some funky stuff on chrome... Thanks I didn't think of this...

Answer (score 1):

@jar, have you tried it on a different machine or tried different browsers? My quick answer would be "no, I haven't seen this happening" and in response to @Daxxy's observation on Browser Link: "I don't see it happening with Browser Link either".

***Long answer, with screenshots:***

I haven't noticed this behavior before, so I installed RC2 on a laptop that I'm currently on, which didn't have RC2 installed it before. I can verify that I do *not* see the observations that you are experiencing.

Here's my _Layout.cshtml for the standard RC2 web template project:
[image: Layout.cshtml screenshot]

Note the meta tags and title tag within the head region.

Now, here's the browser source that reflects the same thing that's in the source code.

[image: Browser source code]

To test out @Daxxy's observation, here's my toolbar menu that shows that Browser Link is enabled:
[image: Enable Browser Link]

Finally, here's a screenshot that shows my Browser Link Dashboard verifying 1 connection to Edge.
[image: Browser Link Dashboard]

If you're still facing this issue on more than one machine with more than one browser, make sure you contact the ASP .NET team with your observations, to check if this is some sort of intentional behavior or a bug.